# fill shape between multiple curves in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found multiple "solutions" on this forum, that either don't quite meet my requirements, or that I just straight fail to reproduce in any form.

I have this tikzpicture:

[image]

Where I want the (masterfully marked in light, and dark gray) areas filled.

## Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
%outer shape
\clip (-8,0) arc (180:-180:8cm and 6cm)coordinate[pos=0.03] (A)coordinate[pos=0.47] (B)coordinate[pos=0.53] (C)coordinate[pos=0.97] (D);
\draw [name path = outer,line width = 1](-8,0) arc (180:-180:8cm and 6cm);

%inner cutout
\draw (-3,.2) .. controls (-2,-0.3) and (-1,-0.5) .. (0,-.5) .. controls (1,-0.5) and (2,-0.3) .. (3,0.2);
\draw (-2.3,-0.1) .. controls (-1.5,0.3) and (-1,0.5) .. (0,.5) .. controls (1,0.5) and (1.5,0.3) .. (2.3,-0.1);

\draw (-8,0) arc (180:-180:8cm and 4cm);
    %scope for shading the outer band
    \begin{scope}
        \draw [dashed, name path = upper lower]let \p1 = (A),\p2 = (B) in (A) arc (180:360:{\x2/2 - \x1/2} and {\x2/4 - \x1/4});
        \draw [dashed, name path = upper upper]let \p1 = (A),\p2 = (B) in (A) arc (-180:-360:{\x2/2 - \x1/2} and {\x2/4 - \x1/4});
        \draw [dashed, name path = lower upper]let \p1 = (C),\p2 = (D) in (C) arc (180:360:{\x2/2 - \x1/2} and {\x2/4 - \x1/4});
        \draw [dashed, name path = lower lower]let \p1 = (C),\p2 = (D) in (C) arc (-180:-360:{\x2/2 - \x1/2} and {\x2/4 - \x1/4});
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If (A) and (B) represent the points where the upper and lower arcs are tangent to the outer ellipse, then the angle should not be 180.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: It helps if you link to the posts you found, even if they didn't give you a solution. And there's no need to put 'solution' in scare quotes just because they didn't solve your issue which, after all, they were not designed to address.